# TeX Live 2012,  XeLaTeX, moderncv, error "Failed to convert input string to UTF16"

Tags: xetex, hyperref, moderncv

I'm getting this error from moderncv version 1.1.1. With earlier version everything was ok and I did not make any changes to my tex document. I don't use any special font. File encoding is set to utf-8. What is the problem?

Comment: There are some changes which are not documented. But we need an example to see your error. At the moment we can guess.

Comment: @Teddy There are some warnings that appear with TL2012 that used to be suppressed: they don't reflect a change of outcome. As Marco says, we could do to see the error to know if this is what you are seeing.

Comment: This is a minimal working example: http://ideone.com/F8Njm

The error is `** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...` and it's printed only once when compiling a document by first time. It's being printed 11 times when document is being compiled twice or more. If I delete *.aux, *.log and *.out files and again do `xelatex template.tex` - it backs to previous state (prints error about UTF16 only once).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`moderncv` loads `hyperref` with the option `unicode`. This leads to the warning as you can try with this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords   = {test}}
\begin{document}
abx
\end{document}
```

The warning is described in section 6 of `readme.pdf` from `hyperref`. The best would be if `moderncv` would not use the option when `xelatex` is used.

Comment: I need `xelatex` because i use `fontspec` package and some packages that handle unicode. Is there any good reason to switch to `pdflatex` or should I stay with `xelatex`?

Comment: I either can't disable this by `\usepackage[unicode=false]{hyperref}` or `\usepackage{hyperref} \hypersetup{unicode=false}`.

Comment: Also with `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}` it complains that `xetex` driver only supports unicode. Seven hells..

Comment: Try `\usepackage[unicode,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}` just before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: You don't need `xelatex` with `fontspec`, you could also use `lualatex`. This is what I use and have no problem with `moderncv`.

Comment: I put `\hypersetup{pdfencoding=auto}` right after loading the document class that loads `hyperref` and it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, when using options like `pdftitle` , `pdfkeywords` , . . .
I changed to use `pdfinfo` and now everything is workng fine. the syntax is like this:

```
\hypersetup{
     pdfinfo={
        Title={My Title},
        Subject={My Subject},
        NewKey={Foobar},
        % ...
             }
           }
```

for more info you can refer to `hyperref`documentation page 11.