# XeLaTeX - terminal output too verbose

Tags: xetex, ubuntu, latexmk

Is it possible to reduce the amount of information you get from running:

```
xelatex texfile.tex
```

The oh so long output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/petr/Dropbox/School/R/3/document.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, sl
ovak, czech, loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2012/05/15 v3.11 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrkbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
Package scrlfile, 2011/03/09 v3.09 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrsize12pt.clo)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/typearea.sty
Package typearea, 2012/05/15 v3.11 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/czech.ldf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3names.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3bootstrap.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3basics.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3expan.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3tl.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3seq.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3int.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3quark.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prg.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3clist.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3token.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3prop.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3msg.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3file.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3skip.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3keys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3fp.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3box.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3coffins.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3color.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3luatex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-patches.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty)
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 107.
*************************************************
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \textsubscript with arg. spec. 's' on line 25.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* LaTeX warning: "xparse/redefine-command"
* 
* Redefining document command \textsuperscript with arg. spec. 's' on line 28.
*************************************************
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/mdframed.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-abspage.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/zref-base.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mdframed/md-frame-0.mdf))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/parskip/parskip.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty)
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Common,TeX' (+liga) not available for font
* 'Times New Roman' with script '' and language ''.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (+onum) not available for font 'Times
* New Roman' with script '' and language ''.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Common,TeX' (+liga) not available for font
* 'Times New Roman' with script '' and language ''.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (+onum) not available for font 'Times
* New Roman' with script '' and language ''.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Common,TeX' (+liga) not available for font
* 'Times New Roman/B' with script '' and language ''.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (+onum) not available for font 'Times
* New Roman/B' with script '' and language ''.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Common,TeX' (+liga) not available for font
* 'Times New Roman/I' with script '' and language ''.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (+onum) not available for font 'Times
* New Roman/I' with script '' and language ''.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Common,TeX' (+liga) not available for font
* 'Times New Roman/BI' with script '' and language ''.
*************************************************
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
* 
* OpenType feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (+onum) not available for font 'Times
* New Roman/BI' with script '' and language ''.
*************************************************
(./document.aux) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./document.out) (./document.out)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n' instead on input line 71.

[1] (./document.toc (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ppl.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omlzplm.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omszplm.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omxzplm.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1zplm.fd)) [2] [3]
<images/bp_consumption.eps> [4] <images/hist_engine.eps> [5]
<images/pie_makes.eps> [6] <images/bar_trans.eps> [7]
(./imports/theoretical_model.tex) (./codes/output.R
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...
** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/Arial/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 2.

) [8] [9]
Overfull \hbox (0.27144pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 204--207
[]\EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/12 Jednotliví \EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/bx/n/12 výrob
ci \EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/12 nám spotřebu ovlivňují určitým směrem. N
apříklad vozy značky Audi ($\OML/zplm/m/it/12 M[]$\EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n/
12 )
[10] (./codes/t_test.txt) [11] (./codes/bp_test.txt)
<images/residual_density.eps> [12** WARNING ** << /Rotate 90 >> found. (Not supported yet)
** WARNING ** << /Rotate 90 >> found. (Not supported yet)
] (./codes/anova.txt) [13] (./codes/robust.txt
) [14] [15] (./R_code.R) [16] [17] (./document.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on document.pdf (17 pages).
Transcript written on document.log.
```

With that, it's hard and very inconvenient to find errors, as they can be missed easily.

Regular `latexmk` output was simple: Saying "There were no errors. However some warnings:" or something similar.

EDIT: my document header:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[czech]{babel} % czech
\usepackage{xltxtra} % fonts
\usepackage{tabularx} % tables
\usepackage{listings} % code listings
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mdframed} % code boxes
\usepackage{enumerate} % numbered items
\usepackage{enumitem} % items
\usepackage{parskip} % no paragraph space
\usepackage[unicode,bookmarks=true]{hyperref} % pdf bookmarks
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % colors
\usepackage{mathpazo} % nicer math font
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % nice header

% Set fonts
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Times New Roman}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\linespread{1.2}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

% Set colors
\definecolor{lightGray}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
% Code box
\newmdenv[backgroundcolor = lightGray, middlelinewidth = 0, linecolor = Gray]{customMdframed}
% Set code listings
\lstset{
    % language = R,
    basicstyle = \fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\ttfamily,
    numberstyle = \fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle = \fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\ttfamily\color{gray},
    backgroundcolor = \color{lightGray},
    breaklines = true,
    breakatwhitespace = true,
    postbreak = {\fontfamily{Arial}{\selectfont →}}\space,
    prebreak = {\fontfamily{Arial}{\selectfont →}}
}
% Define custom wrap
\newcommand{\embedCode}[1]{ \begin{customMdframed} \lstinputlisting{#1} \end{customMdframed} }

% Set header
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Comment: You might want to look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/reducing-the-console-output-of-latex (I think there are also other questions about the log file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was: **rubber**!

It doesn't support XeLaTeX natively, but that can be changed as written on http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=579757.

Comment: Really? AFAIK `rubber` hasn't been developed for a long time. Maybe you want to try arara: http://cereda.github.io/arara/

Comment: @egreg: yep. It doesn't matter, that it's not developed. It works! ;)

Comment: no doubt arara works as well.  reading the post, i was thinking, this problem cries out for an "intelligent log reader" ... which is something most document-maker apps need to use.

Comment: @wasteofspace: well, it depends. Since I'm a programmer and have an editor of choice (sublime text or vim), I need a 3rd party tool like this.

Answer (score 7):

Granted, there is a lot of output but most of the information is context as to where in the process the error/warning is happening. You can try and filter out all the non-error and non-warning lines but you are also removing some of the context information that may be helpful in tracking what is causing the error. This may not be that important with a small document, but it becomes pretty vital with a multiple file several hundred page long document. You rather get used to sorting the output and extracting the relevant information out it with time, and LaTeX is rather good in most cases at highlighting the errors and warnings with new lines. One can at first make the assumption that if the output is just lines and lines of text without empty lines, you have nothing to worry about.

Usually when LaTeX gives you warnings like this, it is for a reason. ignoring these warning means that your output will not be as you expect it to be which is the case here. So the best thing to do is to listen to what the engine say and fix. A lot of the output comes from the fact that you are asking XeLaTeX to do things it can't:

> ```
> *************************************************
> * fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
> * 
> * OpenType feature 'Ligatures=Common,TeX' (+liga) not available for font
> * 'Times New Roman' with script '' and language ''.
> *************************************************
> *************************************************
> * fontspec warning: "icu-feature-not-exist-in-font"
> * 
> * OpenType feature 'Numbers=OldStyle' (+onum) not available for font 'Times
> * New Roman' with script '' and language ''.
> *************************************************
> ```

comes from your definition of `\setmainfont` and the fact that you are requesting options that the font does not support. You should either change your font or remove the offending options:

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} %the common ligature should be enabled by default
```

> ```
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/sc' undefined
> (Font)              using `EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n' instead on input line 71.
> ```

That bit says that the font does not have the small capitals glyph so every time you use them it decided to revert to normal shape. If you do not use `\textsc{}` or `\scshape` you can safely ignore this. If you do use them, then either shange your font or fake the sc.

The repeated

> ** WARNING ** Failed to convert input string to UTF16...

seem to come from `hyperref`. Adding `unicode=true, pdfencoding=auto` to your `\hypersetup` should fix this. (cf. [this tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66722/tex-live-2012-xelatex-moderncv-error-failed-to-convert-input-string-to-utf1) question)

> ```
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/Arial/m/n' undefined
> (Font)              using `EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 2.
> ```

This refers to your listing definition where you use the `\fontfamily{Arial}`, and it tells you that it doesn't understand your request and has decided to replace the font with something it knows, in this case Latin Modern Roman, which is probably not what you want.

You could replace this with `\fontspec{Arial}` or define `Arial` as your document Sans Serif font with `\setsansfont{Arial}` in your preamble and calling `\sffamily` in your listing definition.

Comment: +1, thank you for useful information. Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question completely. Eventhough I have no more warnings and errors, I am getting **lots** of output.

Answer (score 3):

use the option `[quiet]` for the package `fontspec`

Comment: That didn't help. I wasn't including it, but when I tried to, it changed nothing. Editted my question to include to document header...

Comment: with `[quiet]` all warning messages about fonts are gone.

Answer (score 3):

I've found [pplatex](https://github.com/stefanhepp/pplatex) quite useful.  It runs whichever `latex`-like program you want (`xelatex` is one possibility) and summarizes the warnings and errors (and can be used from `latexmk`).

It can also be used as an intelligent log reader, mentioned in a comment to another answer.