# Problems with Cyrillic fonts in XeTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode, moderncv, cyrillic

I have my document with Russian text. Formerly, it was stored as UTF-8 without BOM and compiled with LaTeX. All worked fine with the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{moderncv}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr} % Шрифт с засечками
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss} % Шрифт без засечек
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt} % Моноширинный шрифт
```

But some utilities were not able to identify UTF-8 because of BOM absence, so I added it. From now on LaTeX was unable to compile the document, because of BOM. I switched to XeTeX and replaced preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{moderncv}

% Resolving "Failed to convert input string to UTF16" error. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66722/24133
\usepackage[unicode,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}   %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}  %% устанавливает главный язык документа
\setotherlanguage{english} %% объявляет второй язык документа

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}           %% задаёт основной шрифт документа
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}      %% задаёт шрифт без засечек
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text} %% задаёт моноширинный шрифт

%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr} % Шрифт с засечками
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss} % Шрифт без засечек
%\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt} % Моноширинный шрифт
```

But in this case I got several problems:

1. Fonts are slightly different
2. Italic is missing!
3. Quotes `<<` & `>>` are not parsed

See image before and after:
[image: before]
[image: after]

How to resolve these issues? I suppose that if I can tell XeTeX to use the same non-unicode fonts as LaTeX, it will help.

Please, advice on *all* the issues, since I need them *all* to be fixed.

**PS** I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 (x64) under Windows 7 (x64).

**Update** Example for LaTeX, where everything is fine:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{moderncv}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{cmr}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\name{Михаил \vspace{0.5ex} \\}{Матросов}

\begin{document}

\section{Свои проекты и вклады}

\cvitem{2014}{
    \httplink[\textbf{C++ User Group, Russia}]{meetingcpp.ru}, \emph{Докладчик} \newline{} 
    Доклад \httplink[<<С++ без new и delete>>]{meetingcpp.ru/?p=250}.
}

\end{document}
```

And example for XeTeX, with the mentioned issues (document body hasn't changed):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{moderncv}

% Resolving "Failed to convert input string to UTF16" error. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66722/24133
\usepackage[unicode,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}  
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\name{Михаил \vspace{0.5ex} \\}{Матросов}

\begin{document}

\section{Свои проекты и вклады}

\cvitem{2014}{
    \httplink[\textbf{C++ User Group, Russia}]{meetingcpp.ru}, \emph{Докладчик} \newline{} 
    Доклад \httplink[<<С++ без new и delete>>]{meetingcpp.ru/?p=250}.
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I know, using a BOM for UTF-8 shouldn't be necessary:  "Use of a BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8, but may be encountered in contexts where UTF-8 data is converted from other encoding forms that use a BOM or where the BOM is used as a UTF-8 signature" (From the [Unicode Standard 5.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#cite_note-3))

Comment: @egreg But it the only way I know to make KDiff3 and SmartGit understand UTF-8-encoded files :(

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @Sverre Please, see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not an answer, but a comment can't contain an `MWE` and pictures**

It would be helpful if you did some more work in diagnosing where the problem occurs. Simplifying your example and compiling the code with `XeLaTeX` gives no issues for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}  
\begin{document}
\section{Свои проекты и вклады}
\emph{Докладчик}Доклад <<С++ без new и delete>>.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have different result with the same issues and the following errors: **1)** Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option russian yet. \select@language {russian} **2)** Font shape 'EU1/CMUSerif(0)/m/it' undefined(Font) using 'EU1/CMUSerif(0)/m/n' instead **3)** Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

Comment: @Mikhail You get this error when compiling my ``MWE``? I don't understand why that should happen when there's nothing in this document that mentions the option ``russian`` for ``babel``. Try deleting your auxiliary files before compiling again.

Comment: Deleted .aux file, error 1) is now gone, but result is the same.

Comment: @Mikhail As indicated in my answer, please do some work in diagnosing where the problems occur, and edit your original question, and post a _minimal_ example. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with ``moderncv``, ``polyglossia``, etc.

Comment: Currently I decided to switch back to LaTeX without BOM. Shame on me. Tanks for your help!